# Adjust height dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following snippets in my code that help me achieve a fixed-top-navigation-on-scroll.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-static-top hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-header" aria-controls="navbar-header">
        &#9776;
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="navbar-header">
        <img class="navbar-brand" src="pics/logonavigation.png"/>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link smoothScroll" href="#navigation">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link smoothScroll" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link smoothScroll" href="#services">OUR SERVICES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link smoothScroll" href="#contact">CONTACT US</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
       var navHeight = $( window ).height() - $('nav').height();
             if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
                 $('nav').addClass('fixed');
             }
             else {
                 $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
             }
        });

       $('.navbar-toggler').click(function() {
        var newHeight = $('nav').height();
            $(".fixed").height(newHeight);
       });
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed {
position: fixed;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
top: 0;
z-index: 1;
height: 50px;
}
```

The entire file pastebin can be found [HERE](http://pastebin.com/xB9zmi1i)

I am using bootstrap v4

Viewing the site in mobile view the following is observed:[image]

The collapsible portion of the navigation is left "bare" without the black background. What I would like is to get the effect below:

[image]

I cannot use the class "navbar" at  because somehow it interferes with the fixed-top-navigation-on-scroll. How can I get the background of the collpasible portion of the navigation in mobile view to appear black? I tried adjusting the height of .fixed dynamically using jquery but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to put your code into something more universally used like JSfiddle or CodePen.

Since I don't have a Pastebin account and can't easily run the code, I'll take a guess. Based on what I can see here, because your nav is gaining the `.fixed` class with a fixed `height: 50px;`, you're not going to get the black background behind the menu because it's only `50px` tall.

Try changing it to `height: auto;`, assuming height is 50px before it gains `.fixed`. I'd also add a `transition: height Xs;` on it because when `height` is set to `auto`, it will "grow" to cover the menu.

**EDIT**

One big issue here is that you've declared a `top` AND `bottom` value on `.nav`. This was causing the full height for the `.fixed` nav. So remove that.

Then change the second half of your jQuery to this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.navbar-toggler').click(function() {
    $('nav').css('height', 'auto');
  });
})
```

So when `.navbar-toggler` is clicked, we add `height: auto;` to the `nav`.

This worked for me upon testing, as far as getting the navbar to expand to include the menu items without going full browser height.

I recognize that pulling `bottom: 0` out from `nav` will cause placement issues relative to `#screen1`, but I don't understand why you put the `nav` inside that section anyway. I would put it between `#section1` and `#section2`.

You could change the height for `#section1` to be `calc(100vh - 50px)` so that the navbar fits perfectly at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I have tried using both codepen and jsfiddle but the menu doesn't even show as it does on my pc locally.

Comment: Height: auto makes the background cover the entire page as soon as it reaches the top

Comment: That's because your file paths aren't linking to anything if you paste the code into a code sharing platform, since they're links relative to your local folder structure. I've figured some more of this out. Will edit my answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer, @AndreaTand. Hope this helps more.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. Worked

Comment: Awesome! Good luck on the rest of your project, Andrea.